# CSS Min-Height "vh" Property

Tags: html, css

I need to specify min-height at several places so I did this,

```
body{
    min-height = 100vh;
}
```

But it's not working, it's not doing anything. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're looking for `min-height: 100vh` instead of `min-height = 100vh`.

Also note that `<body>` adds `8px` of `margin` by default, so if you don't want any scrollbars, you'll also need to offset this with `margin: 0` when using **[viewport-relative lengths](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)**:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Sorry, my fault, i've edited the question. But it's still not working. I want a little scrolling independent of the size of content. But it's not working

Comment: @Randomix You'll need to provide some more detail then, because what you've provided works.

Comment: Sir, i've also added * {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;}

Comment: Is it the problem?

Comment: @Randomix Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now nothing you've posted would break anything.

Comment: The above snippet I have provided is working as expected. Start with that, and then simply build upon it until it breaks. It's possible that CSS caching is an issue for you; ensure you refresh your index with `CTRL` + `F5`, and clear your CSS cache by holding `SHIFT` while clicking on the refresh icon.

Answer (score 0):

CSS uses colon to assign values. Using `min-height: 100vh;` should work fine.

Comment: Sorry, my fault i've edited the question but still it's not working